# How to programmatically close A WearableActionDrawerView when using the new support library version?

Tags: java, android, wear-os, android-wear-2.0

In my Android wear application I have a `WearableActionDrawerView` contained withen a `WearableDrawerLayout`.

The problem that I am having is that I cannot figure out how to close the ActionDrawer programmatically.

Normally I would use the `closeDrawer()` method, however I am using the new version in the support library which is in the `android.support.wear` namespace (instead of the old `wearable` namespace) and there is no such method.

I have tried looking in the docs for both the ActionDrawer Located 
 here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/wear/widget/drawer/WearableActionDrawerView

As well as in the docs for the parent `WearableDrawerLayout` located here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/wear/widget/drawer/WearableDrawerLayout

And not only couldn't I find a `closeDrawer()` method, but I could not find any reference or method in the documentation as to how to close the drawer programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I had to first use the `getController()` method to get access to the drawer controller and then on the WearDrawerController object call the `closeDrawer()` method.

That's it.